# How can we download multiple CSV files from a URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am testing this code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


d = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Utility\\chromedriver.exe')
d.get('https://developers.humana.com/Resource/PCTFilesList?fileType=innetwork')

# stuck here...
#links = 
for link in links:
    d.get(link)
    # click page 2, 3, 4, etc., up to 100
    for page in range(1, 100)
    page.click
d.quit()
```

So, I am trying to download CSV files on page 1, then click page 2 and download those files, and then click page 3 and again download those files. The sample code that I shared here should be a start, I think, but it definitely needs some improvements to work right.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you know how to "click page 2"?  If you do, the rest is easy.

Comment: If i right click on the '2' at the bottom of the page and click 'Inspect (Q)' I see this:
<a href="#" aria-controls="dtBasicExample" data-dt-idx="2" tabindex="0">2</a>

The weird thing is that the URL doesn't change when you click 2, 3, 4, etc. I have seen that behavior with a few other URLs.

Comment: It seems to change the next  data-dt-idx to 5 on about page 5 it seems.

Comment: You can get all files names (just adjust last parameter iDisplayLength):  https://developers.humana.com/Resource/GetData?fileType=innetwork&sEcho=1&iColumns=3&sColumns=%2C%2C&iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength=1000   and then just put file name in url https://developers.humana.com/Resource/DownloadPCTFile?fileType=innetwork&fileName=2022-06-24_1_in-network-rates_000000000001.csv.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```
import requests

length = 1
url = "https://developers.humana.com/Resource/GetData?fileType=innetwork&sEcho=1&iColumns=3&sColumns=%2C%2C\
                                                                                                &iDisplayStart=0&iDisplayLength="

r = requests.get(url+str(length))
json_data = r.json()

length = json_data['iTotalRecords']
print("files ", length)
r = requests.get(url+str(length))
json_data = r.json()

for e in json_data['aaData']:
    download_url = "https://developers.humana.com/Resource/DownloadPCTFile?fileType=innetwork&fileName=" + e['name']
    print(e['name'])
    print("download url: ", download_url)
```

then just download files in loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
wait = WebDriverWait(d, 20)
d.get('https://developers.humana.com/Resource/PCTFilesList?fileType=innetwork')
for i in range(2,101):
    time.sleep(1)
    j=i
    if i>5:
        j=5
    #links=d.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.download-pct-file-link")
    #print(len(links))
    #for link in links:
        # link.click()
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//a[@data-dt-idx='{j}']"))).click()
    print(f"//a[@data-dt-idx='{j}']")
```

I got it to go through the pages while switching the value to click to be 5 after page 5.data-dx-idx went from 2-5 then stayed at 5.You can most likely do it without time.sleep() if you handle the stales.

Import:

```
import time
```

Comment: This iterates through all the pages, which is super-cool, but it doesn't download any CSV file from any page. I tried this approach: target = d.find_element_by_link_text('.csv')
    target.click()

I tried this too: d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='download-pct-file-link']")).click()

How can I download multiple CSV files from one page then iterate to the next page and do it again?

Comment: I think there is a better approach to solving the problem, as Max described above. Your solution is quite elegant, thanks for that. I think using JSON is ultimately the best option here.

Comment: Yeah didn't know you could have got the urls.

Comment: I realized that after I posted my question. Thanks though! Your solution was very interesting too!